# HELP! Calling another contract not working

Tags: solidity

```
Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.8)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)
```

My Token

```
contract ERC20Token {
    function contractTransfer(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        // bla.bla.bla....
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Contract which can transfer the token

```
import "./ERC20Token.sol";

contract MyContract {
    ERC20Token public Coin;

    constructor (address coin) {
        Coin = ERC20Token(coin);
    }

    function Test(address from, address to, uint amount) public {
        // bla...bla..lba...
        Coin.contractTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

The code above was simplified. Security is not a concern for this question.

The code used to work until I have upgraded truffle to 4.1.8 and solc = 4.23.

Previously was using truffle = 4.1.3 and solc = 4.19

I can't invoke contractTransfer from MyContract. May I know what had changed?

Comment: The code you've shared looks fine, so this question seems to be unanswerable until you provide us with your _actual_ code, the error you're receiving, and complete steps for how to reproduce that error.

Comment: smarx, thanks for the answer. The code above works fine until I upgraded both truffle and solc. I am also confused now. I didn't make any changes. Except solidity forces me to use the constructor keyword.

Comment: I downgrade back to truffle 4.1.3 and solc 4.1.9, the problem is gone automagically. The earlier transaction was failed, because code compiled with the latest version consumed extra ordinary high amount of ether until the transaction was out of gas.

Comment: What is the error? compiler failure or runtime failure. As stated by smarx the code here works as expected, if there's an issue it is in another part of the code.

Comment: Compiler only gives some warning about the change of constructor keyword. No error. The problem was during runtime. It consumed all my ethers (more than 50ETH) and failed after running out of gas. Problem gone when I down grade to 4.1.3

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3969